# Method does not exist in business hour?

Tags: businesshours

```
BusinessHours oBh = [SELECT Name,Id FROM BusinessHours where name='FR'];
datetime leaCreatedDate =DateTime.now();

Long slaSeconds =864000000;

system.debug('oBh<<'+oBh.id);

system.debug('oBh<<'+oBh.add(oBh.id,leaCreatedDate,slaSeconds));
```

Am getting error in the last debug statment.Please correct me

Comment: what you want to do here?

Comment: This method does exist but you are using it incorrectly. [BusinessHours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm) method add() will return a DateTime. It is very unclear as to what you are trying to achieve here. Please elaborate and we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `.add` is used for the BusinessHours **class** not for the BusinessHours **object**. You probably want to do something like.

```java
BusinessHours oBh = [SELECT Name,Id FROM BusinessHours where name='FR'];
DateTime leaCreatedDate = DateTime.now();

Long slaSeconds = 864000000L;

system.debug('oBh<<'+oBh.id);

DateTime slaTime = BusinessHours.add(oBh.id,leaCreatedDate,slaSeconds);
system.debug('oBh<<'+slaTime);
```